# Sitecore 8: EXM 3.1 Update 1 (3.1.1) not showing the email templates

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-ecm

I upgrade the EXM to version 3.1 Update 1 (3.1.1).
Now when I go to create an One time message I don't see my email templates. 
I have add the email templates using the Insert options as bellow.

[image]

But still I don't see my email templates when try to create an One time message.

[image]

Comment: Anything useful in the error logs?  When I've opened up the one-time message interface and it only has "HTML file" as an option, I found that something was corrupt with the install.

Comment: Having another problem. I have build the solution. Then the EXM 3.1.1 dll's getting replace by EXM 3.0 dll's. Any idea on this ?

Comment: Sounds like you've got the wrong DLLs in your solution and they are getting pushed out to your deployment location.

Answer (score 1):

EXM looks in the Message Type folders, in this case "One Time Message", and finds the **first** item with the right template, in this case "OneTime".  Try moving your "Default" node to the top of the "One Time Message" folder.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem. But I've carefully read PDF file instruction for upgrade ([Sitecore EXM 3.1](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Email_Experience_Manager/Email_Experience_Manager_31/Email_Experience_Manager_31_Initial_Release.aspx)) and found solution:

For each EXM manager root, change the item name of the following items:

- /Message Types/One Time Message item (item name Adhoc)
  to
  /Message Types/OneTime
- /Message Types/Subscription Message item (item name Periodical)
  to
  /Message Types/Subscription
- /Message Types/Triggered Message item (item name Trickle)
  to
  /Message Types/Triggered