# Sitecore 8.2 : EXM 3.3 update 1 not showing the email templates on creating Regular campaign

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-exm

We have recently upgraded EXM from 3.3 to 3.5 update 1 version. After upgrade, the email templates are not appearing on creating Regular campaign. We made sure that templates are assigned in content editor.

On clicking regular campaign, a window pop ups with no templates.

Have gone through the below link and changed the item name of the following:

[Sitecore 8: EXM 3.1 Update 1 (3.1.1) not showing the email templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34039982/sitecore-8-exm-3-1-update-1-3-1-1-not-showing-the-email-templates)

1. /Message Types/One Time Message item (item name Adhoc) to /Message
   Types/OneTime
2. /Message Types/Subscription Message item (item name
   Periodical) to /Message Types/Subscription
3. /Message Types/Triggered    Message item (item name Trickle) to /Message
   Types/Triggered

No errors in log files.

Anyone faced similar kind of issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed. We found that the item name "One Time" & "Triggered" should have got updated as "Regular" & "Automated" respectively as part of upgrade.
This was not happened during upgrade.

After changing the name, it worked.

Path of the item;

- /sitecore/content/New Manager Root/Message Types/Regular
- /sitecore/content/New Manager Root/Message Types/Automated